# Bayesian versus Classical (frequentist) Statistics

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Very often in text-books the comparison of Bayesian vs. Classical Statistics are presented upfront in a very abstract way. For example, in the current book I'm studying there's the following postulates of both school of thoughts:

> "Within the field of statistics there are two prominent schools of thought, with op­posing views: the Bayesian and the classical (also called frequentist). Their fundamental difference relates to the nature of the unknown models or variables.
>
> **In the Bayesian view they are treated as random variables with known distributions. In the classical view, they are treated as deterministic quantities that happen to be unknown.**"

But as a beginner student in this field there's a lack of 'substance', of something you can 'feel'. So would I like to know, if somebody has a real world example of both cases. Like the same example, but seen from both perspectives to help understanding 'what's going on'. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A good way to understand how these two perspectives differ is to look at how they approach the problem of confidence intervals.  The question [What's the difference between a confidence interval and a credible interval?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval) has some excellent discussion on this, including examples where both approaches are taken and shown to give different answers.